# Multiple Columns within each list item

Tags: css, wordpress, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I have a wordpress generated list with the main data on the left and supplemental data floated on the right.

Currently, I have three pieces of information that is displayed on the right, but because the widths vary slightly, the overall look of the list is not as clean or easy to use as it could be.

I would like the 3 items on the right, to be equal width, so there is a clear vertical distinction between each item.

Here is the page: http://www.runthinkshootlive.com/ep2/

Any ideas?

TIA

Comment: Please post your code for that section.

Comment: I pasted it here:  http://pastebin.com/p91djRMY

Comment: I think this is a perfect example on when to use a table. If you want a table layout use it.